# Why crontab is not able to run a script which contains a "for" loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, cron

```
#!/bin/sh
#
TEMP_FILE=/home/eceadcb/Test_Directory_5/temp.txt

echo "ABC" >> ${TEMP_FILE}
for i in $(<Active_cms.txt)
do
    echo "ABC1" >> ${TEMP_FILE}
    echo "$i" >> ${TEMP_FILE}
done
```

When I run this script manually, it runs just fine. But when I schedule it in crontab, only ABC goes in the TEMP_FILE and nothing from loop gets into the file.

Comment: Add full path to `Active_cms.txt`.

Comment: Btw.: `/bin/sh` is not `bash`.

Comment: Btw.: Replace `for` loop by `while` loop.

Comment: I need to use for loop only. Adding full path is not helping.

Comment: `sh` does not know `$(<filename)` syntax. Use `bash`.

Comment: Then how is it able to run standalone if sh does not know $(<filename) ?

Comment: I assume you use `bash` and you use `sh` in the script.

Comment: If `/bin/sh` on your machine is actually a version of `bash`, it will work. But if your script relies on `bash`-only features, don't use `#!/bin/sh` as the shebang; use `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever path is appropriate).

Comment: how should I set it in crontab then?
I am using * * * * * /bin/sh /home/eceacdb/Test_dir/test.sh
<test.sh> is name of script.

Comment: Replace`/bin/sh` by output of `which bash`.

Comment: @chepner: I agree with you.

Comment: See: [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296/3776858)

Comment: changed it to /bin/bash but it is still not working. only got ABC in the TEMP_FILE

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Add `inputfile=/path/to/Active_cms.txt; ls -l "${inputfile}"` above the `for-loop` and see if that is what you expected.